# Событие после выбора даты

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5

```
<input name="select_user" type="date"  min="<?echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
```

Подскажите как сделать так, что бы при выборе даты на сегодня, появилось событие например:  `alert('Вы выбрали +curdate+ что = сегодня');`, до того как форма отправится.

Comment: событие onChange?

Comment: @Node_pro Большое Спасибо!

Comment: скрипт помочь написать?

Comment: @Node_pro Не, получилось, почитал и понял принцип js, в принципе тоже самое как и php. Работает так:  <input onchange="if (this.value=='<? echo  date('Y-m-d');?>'){Alert.render('Обращаем Ваше внимание, что заявка на сегодня, только с согласованием администратора. ')}" name="select_user" id="select_user" type="date"  min="<? echo  date('Y-m-d');?>" class="form-control">